# Writing a function for F(n)=0.5F(n-1)

Tags: c, recursion, time-complexity

> let F(n)=0.5F(n-1) and F(0)=1
>
> a. write a function fun1, a recursive function to evaluate the n's term
>
> b. write a function fun2, a non recursive function to evaluate the n's term
>
> c. what is the time complexity of fun1 and from which n term it will be better to use fun1 vs fun2 regarding space complexity

In general the function evaluate the n term of the sequence {1,1/2,1/4,1/8,...}

a.

```
 double fun1( int n ){
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0.5*fun1(n-1);
}
```

b.

```
double fun2( int n ){
    double sum = 1, i;
    for (i=0 ; i < n; i++)
        sum=sum*(0.5);
    return sum;
}
```

c. Intuitively and mathematically using the sum of geometric sequence we can show that it is `O(n)`

1. is there another way?
2. how to address space complexity?

Comment: A thought regarding space complexity: (leaving tail recursion optimization aside) `fun1()` will have to consume n stack frames (or call contexts or whatever) where `fun2()` will consume always exactly 1.

Comment: @Scheff `0.5*fun1(n-1)` is never tail recursion because it needs to do multiplication with the result.

Comment: @Sylwester It seems I overrated what modern compilers are able to recognize. I fiddled a bit with newest gcc and clang in godbolt which "proved" you right. Glad that I wrote "_may_ happen"... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

While your versions of *fun1* and *fun2* are of different space complexity, their time complexity is *O(n)*.

However, the non-recursive function can also be written as:

```
#import <math.h>

double fun2(int n) {
    return pow(0.5, n);
}
```

This function is of space and time complexity *O(1)* and will be more efficient for most *n* (probably *n* > 5).

As for the original question: It's very tricky as it depends on the compiler optimization:

A naive implementation is of *fun1* is of space complexity *O(n)* as a call of *fun1(n)* will have a recursive depth of *n* and therefore requires *n* call frames on the stack. On most systems it will only work up to a certain *n*. Then you get a *Stack Overflow* error because the stack has a limited size.

An optimizing compiler will recognize that it's a tail-recursive function and will optimize it into something very close to *fun2*, which has a space complexity of *O(1)* as it uses a fixed number of variable with a fixed size independent of *n* and no recursion.

Comment: You should clarify that you're talking about time complexity, because the question is also about space complexity.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this is a homework question so I will not refer anything about compiler optimizations and tail recursion since this is not property of the program itself but it depends on the compiler if it will optimize a recursive function or not..

Your first approach is clearly O(n) since it calls recursively f1 and all it does a multiplication.

Your second approach is also clearly O(n) since it is just a simple loop.
So as for time complexity both are the same O(n)

As for space complexity fun1 needs n function records so it is O(n) space complexity while fun2 only needs one variable so it is O(1) space complexity. So as for space complexity fun2 is a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

For a recursive and iterative approach the complexity can be reduced to *O(log n)*:

The recursive depth of the following solution is *log n*:

```cpp
double fun3( int n ){

    double f;
    if ( n == 0 )
        return 1.0;

    f = fun3( n/2 );
    return f * f * (n % 2 ? 0.5 : 1.0);
}
```

The number of iterations in the following loop is *log n*, too:

```cpp
double fun4( int n ){

    int i;
    double f = (n % 2 ? 0.5 : 1.0);
    for (i = n; i > 1; i /= 2)
        f *= 0.5*0.5;

    return f;
}
```

Comment: What about it? What is it supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can answer yourself if you take a look on the generated code: https://godbolt.org/z/Gd9XxM

1. It is very likely that the optimizing compiler will remove the tail recursion.
2. Space and time complexity strongly depend on the optimization options (Try -Os, -O0)

Comment: I am looking for a naive approach :) but thanks for the advanced approach